Correct algebraic notation for contrasts from statistical model
In a pre-post study, we can use a linear mixed model to estimate the treatment effect as the coefficient of the time x treatment interaction, see here (section 19.3):
https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/models-for-longitudinal-experiments-pre-post-designs.html
Suppose we extend this model to several follow-up periods and model time using a regression spline. The coefficients will be uninterpretable, but we can compute a series of conditional/marginal contrasts at each followup measurement time to estimate the treatment effect i.e. difference-in-differences between predicted values. Im thinking of the types of contrasts that we can get using post estimation tools e.g. in R the packages emmeans, marginaleffects, rms, and the like. However, I do not know how to write such contrasts properly algebraically. My attempt is attached as an image below (sorry I couldn't work out how to write directly on this site).

where I is the intervention effect, y is the response variable, x are predictor variables, t is a series of followup times, t0 is baseline time, T is treatment group, and C is control group.
I would be most grateful if somebody can help to correct / write this properly for me in algebraic notation for the case of contrasts from a linear model assuming normally distributed errors. And also how this generalizes to a Poisson model with a log link. In that case, the difference-in-difference becomes a ratio of rate ratios on the response scale, but again I'm uncertain how to write this properly using algebraic notation.
